# Pointer to array of string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I don't understand this part of code:

```
char *arrStr[3];
arrStr[0] = "hola";    //works
*(arrStr+1) = "guys";  //works
arrStr++;              // doesn't work why?

char **arrStr2 = arrStr; //works
arrStr2++; //works
```

I don't understand why `arrStr++` doesn't work while `arrStr2` works.

This is strange because I'm doing the same thing, but in one case it works in the other not, why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*arrStr[3]` is an array of 3 pointers to `char` while `**arrStr2` a pointer to a pointer to `char`. In

```
arrStr[0] = "hola";
```

`arrStr` is an array and array names are **nonmodifiable l-values** and hence you can't modify it. On the other hand modification can be done on `arrStr` as it is a pointer to pointer but not an array. Do remember that ***arrays are not pointers***.

Answer (score 2):

`arrStr` is an array of pointers, you can't modify an array name. `arrStr++;` won't compile.

`arrStr2` is a pointer to a pointer, you can modify a pointer. And you should consider a better name, as it's not an array.

Comment: @GiovanniFar An array name is automatically converted to a pointer to the first element in some situations(like passed as function argument), but no, **arrays are not pointers**.

Comment: ok but both have a reference ... so i cannot see the difference

Comment: thanks so much. now is clear. with an array i'm moving direclty inside the array, with the point i change just target and after i fetch it. but all the process is inside to the reference of the pointer. with the array no... i have a reference but i go direclty there and i move position there. with the pointer you remain inside it and increment there the reference and in the end you go to fetch the value inside at this reference

Answer (score 0):

```
char *arrStr[3];
```

if you use the array name as a pointer,you must know that this pointer is a `const` pointer, so you can't do the `++` or `--` operator, `char *str = "ciao";` just declare a normal pointer, you can do every to it.